# Shrink and sticky UIImageView on scroll?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a `UIScrollView` in my iOS app. In the `UIScrollView` I have a `UITextView` and a `UIImageView`. What I need is for the `UIImageView` to scroll until it's bottom is about 33% removed from the top of the screen and then stick.

This is my `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    UIScrollView *scrollView =[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, 758);

    self.view = scrollView;

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [self.stream plaatje]];

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-164)];
    [self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tile-blue.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];

UITextView *content = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-100, self.view.bounds.size.width,     self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    content.text = textString;
    content.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    content.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    content.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Regular" size:18];
    content.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    [content sizeToFit];
    [content layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.view addSubview:content];

    CGFloat width = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat imageHeight = CGRectGetMaxY(self.imageView.frame);
    CGFloat contentHeight = CGRectGetMaxY(content.frame);
    [scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(width, contentHeight))];
}
```

Now, I did some research on this and I'm 95% sure I need to do it with:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGRect headerFrame = self.imageView.frame;
    headerFrame.origin.y = MAX(self.imageView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    self.imageView.frame = headerFrame;
}
```

Although the current implementation does nothing. How can I solve this?